# Nevertheless or notwithstanding, which is correct?

Tags: word-choice

The school is strict about hair styles; (　　　), some students break the rules.

The correct answer is supposed to be nevertheless. But can't notwithstanding also be correct in this sentence? Can someone explain why not? Thank you.

Comment: Only if you change the structure. They are different categories of words. You can say "The school's strict rules notwithstanding, some students (...)"

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, "**nevertheless**" has the meaning of "**however**"

> The school is strict about hair styles; **nevertheless**, some students break the rules.
>   *The school is strict about hair styles; **however**, some students break the rules.*

In your second example, "**notwithstanding**" has more the meaning of "**eventhough**"

> **Notwithstanding** the school's strict rules about hair styles; some students *(still)* break the rules.
>   **Even though** the school has strict rukes about hair styles; some students break the rules.

Comment: "Eventhough" is not a word.

Answer (score 1):

The default function of **notwithstanding** is [a preposition](http://thefreedictionary.com/notwithstanding). It is similar to "despite". It is used alongside those factors that do not preclude something. For example,

> **Notwithstanding** the school's strict **rules**, some students still come to school with weird hair styles.

So, "notwithstanding" is a preposition that is "pre-positioned" before the word "rules". Often, "notwithstanding" can be used *in post-position*:

> (The school's strict rules **notwithstanding**, some students still come to school with weird hair styles.)

—but the correct term for it as part of speech is still "preposition.")

Only in its *second* function as adverb is it equated with "nevertheless", and in this *adverbial* meaning, it usually comes *after* the statement that it qualifies.

However, **nevertheless** is and can only be [an adverb](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nevertheless), so it can be inserted into a sentence on its own.

In your case, something standalone needs to be inserted. The first choice is "nevertheless."